# Not able to import private gitlab repository

Tags: go, gitlab, go-get

I am trying to import a private gitlab repository into my Go code.
I want to use the user access token for authentication. Is there a way in which I could pass the access token in the import command.

I tried using the basic oauth2 url in the import command, but the import command only accepts a path.

Answer (score 1):

You can run command

```
git config --global url.git@gitlab.com:.insteadOf https://gitlab.com/
```

and try again, it'll use your git credential to work with gitlab.

For example, your repository is located at https://gitlab.com/yourname/hello

you run

```
go get gitlab.com/yourname/hello
```